# Bootstrap Model not showing properly

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

The Same code I have in my Page. Whenever i am clicking on the button, the model get call and shows the model dialogbox just for few seconds and then become invisable.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
<td class="text-center"><a class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete" ></a></td>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> Confirm Delete </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure you want to Delete  contact list ?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <a  id="sureDelete"><button  class="btn btn-danger success">Delete</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code i have from http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Comment: Did you include   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have included locally in my page
bootstrap.css
bootstrap.js
jquery.js
bootstrap.min.js

Comment: either use `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`... Not both.. both are same

Comment: Using This Script to call my model

<script>$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('show');
    });
</script>

Comment: And Facing this error while inspecting in browser console
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function get_emp_ajax:274:3

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code, it will work. Bootstrap's docs is pretty well, you can follow that also. http://getboostrap.com

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: are you sure? try to run this code in a separate file it will work.

Comment: you might have included the jquery file twice. Please make sure everything is correct.